People picker: Network error when using Patch function: Length must be between 0 and 100
Upon adding creator kit people picker to an app, following the instructions here, I get the error when searching for someone:
Network error when using Patch function: Length must be between 0 and 100
I've added to the OnSearch property of the control:
ClearCollect(
    UserCollection,
    AddColumns(
        Filter(
            Office365Users.SearchUser(
                {
                    searchTerm: Self.SearchText,
                    top: 500
                }
            ),
            !(Mail in Self.SelectedPeople.PersonaKey)
        ),
        SuggestionImgUrl,
        Substitute(
            JSON(
                Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(Id),
                JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData
            ),
            """",
            ""
        ),
        SuggestionKey,
        Mail,
        SuggestionName,
        DisplayName,
        SuggestionRole,
        JobTitle,
        SuggestionPresence,
        "away"
    )
)

And to the Suggestion Items: UserCollection.
